# FormRequest message in laravel 8 not show messages

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-validation

In my laravel 8 app I am trying to create two files `CreateUserRequest` and `updateUserRequest` to use personalized validations.

In the method `rules` I´m calling my model's variable `$createRules` but when I send my form, this don´t send, don´t show messages, error... Nothing.

I have attached `CreateUserRequest`, my `model` and controller's `store` method:

#### CreateUserRequest

```php
namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;
use App\Models\User;

class CreateUserRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return User::$createRules;
    }
}
```

#### Model

```php
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Spatie\Permission\Traits\HasRoles;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, HasRoles;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
        'surname',
        'experience',
        'skills',
        'education',
        'location',
        'profesion',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public static $createRules = [
        'name'       => 'required|string|max:191',
        'email'      => 'required|string|email|max:191|unique:users',
        'password'   => 'required|min:4|max:10|confirmed',
    ];

    public static $updateRules = [
        'name'  => 'required|string|max:191',
        'email' => 'required|string|email|max:191|unique:users',
    ];
}
```

#### Controller's `store` method

```php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateUserRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateUserRequest;
use App\Models\Role;
use App\Models\User;
use Flash;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Intervention\Image\ImageManagerStatic as Image;
use JamesDordoy\LaravelVueDatatable\Http\Resources\DataTableCollectionResource;
use Prettus\Validator\Exceptions\ValidatorException;

public function store(CreateUserRequest $request)
{
    try {
        $data = array(
            'name'      => $request->get('name'),
            'email'     => $request->get('email'),
            'password'  => password_hash($request->get('password'), PASSWORD_BCRYPT),
            'api_token' => Str::random(60),
        );

        $user = User::create($data);
        $roles = $request->get('roles');

        // We assign the Client's role
        if(empty($roles)) {
            $user->assignRole(2);
        } else {
            foreach($roles as $rol){
                $user->assignRole($rol);
            }
        }
    } catch (ValidatorException $e) {
        Flash::error($e->getMessage());
    }

    Flash::success('This is a message!');
    
    return redirect()->route('users.index');
}
```

In the `blade` I have `@include('flash::message')` for getting flashed messages, and this view it´s included in other `@include('admin.layouts.alertMessage')`.

I don´t know what I am doing wrong.

Thanks for help me and sorry for my bad English.

**UPDATED**

my problem i think that i don´t arrive to my controller. I´m doin echo in my function with one exit and load all my page without message echo

attach my form and my routes:

```
<form action="{{ route('users.store') }}" method="POST">
    @csrf
    @include('admin.users.fields')
</form>
```

**routes**

```
/** USERS BLOQ ROUTES */
Route::resource('users', UserController::class);
```

Comment: What is your `flash::message` doing ? If you want to pass `flashed` data to a view, you just do `return redirect()->route('users.index')->with(['message' => 'This is a message!');` but if it is something custom, I understand why you are calling `Flash::success`. You have to show what `Flash::success` do and the view that uses it so we can tell you what is wrong.

Comment: this library, its: laracasts/flash and with this get all messages

Comment: @matiaslauriti thanks for your response i updated my question with my problem that i think...

Comment: if you do `dd('testing')` on your `store` as the first line of code, do you see or get `testing` back or not ? Maybe your `FormRequest` is not passing.

Comment: @matiaslauriti same result, always reload page, but not stopped execution

Comment: Then, your `FormRequest` is stopping you, it is not passing the validations... Try changing it to a normal `Request` so it does not stop you and tell me if you now see `testing`.

Comment: @matiaslauriti yes, now yes...

Comment: So, you have `errors` (rules not passing). Read how to display them on the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/validation#quick-displaying-the-validation-errors).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TBH, i didn't know that you can get validation logic from their Model. My advice is just copy paste your validation logic to the request. Since Request is only for Validation purpose ( CMIIW )

**CreateRequest**

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name'       => 'required|string|max:191',
            'email'      => 'required|string|email|max:191|unique:users',
            'password'   => 'required|min:4|max:10|confirmed',
        ];
    }
```

**UpdateRequest**

```
public function rules()
        {
            return [
                'name'  => 'required|string|max:191',
                'email' => 'required|string|email|max:191|unique:users',
            ];
        }
```

**UPDATE**

Just combine it to one Requests, give **RequiredIf** for *password* request, in case your update route contains *update*

```
use Illuminate\Validation\Rule;
...

public function rules()
{
    return [
          'password' => Rule::requiredIf(str_contains(url()->current(), 'update')) . '|min:4|max:10|confirmed',
    ]
}
```

Comment: yes, my rules it´s to other proyect that use this form...

Comment: It is the same, `function rules()` needs to have a `return ARRAY`, if that array comes from another class (does not matter which one) or if it comes from a helper function, is the same, it just needs to return an `array` in the correct format. But I do agree with your statement, I do not like to see *imports* or similar from other places, I like to literally see the rules there because this validations are only for the controller or whoever is using it, so it should be nearly unique.